# mysql_query function in php

Tags: php, mysql, oracle

```
<?php 
  $con= mysql_connect("localhost","root","mysql");
  mysql_select_db("Db_name",$con);

  $res=mysql_query("select *from table_name");

  mysql_close($con);   // closing connection before fetching contents.

  while($r=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo $r['ename'];
  }

?>
```

This programs works even if i close the connection before fetching contents from the table.

In order get table contents from the `$res` connection is not necessary ?

Is`$res` just a program variable ? If so what kind  of data structure it is using(associative array ? )

In oracle we have implicit cursor and explicit cursor. Are there any equivalent things in mysql?

In the above program where cursors come into picture ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$res` in your case is a special type called a "Resource". Simply put it is a collection of the data returned which the mysql_fetch_* functions operate. As such, it can live beyond the connection. Check [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

The MySQL client library will fetch the whole result set before the call to `mysql_query()` returns which explains why your code works.

You can use `mysql_unbuffered_query()` to fetch the rows incrementally *in which case you must keep the connection open*.

Note that  fetching the rows is handled inside the MySQL client code. `$res` is just an opaque *ressource type* that represents an internal resultset object (buffered or not). You can only operate on that ressource by passing it to other MySQL functions.

Answer (score 0):

> In order get table contents from the $res connection is not necessary ?

Why did not you try it and see?

Anyway, what is the reason to close connection manually?

> Is $res just a program varible ? If so what kind of data structure it is using(associative array ?

Yes, it is a variable. You can see what is inside with `var_dump($res);`

> In oracle we have implicit cursor and explicit cursor.Are there any equivalent things in mysql ?
>   In the above program where cursors come into picture ?

What exact task are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am not trying to solve any task.... trying to learn concepts by implementing programs. var_dump($res) is displaying resource(5) of type (mysql result).what is 5 here ?

Comment: @Jagan: It is just a resource number. The many resources (file handler, mysql_connection/result, ...) you create - the bigger number it holds.

Comment: @Jagan: cursors in mysql are available in stored procedures. There is no reasons to work with them directly in php. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cursors.html

Comment: Can i know about cursors.I did not understand the importance of cursors.

Comment: @Jagan: it is a way to iterate through a result set.

Answer (score 0):

As jason said $res is just like a normal variable of type Resource. This variable holds its value even after the mysql connection is closed as it has no connection with the mysql connection.